# I need to connect my ethernet port to the internet using WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

Is this something I can use?

https://www.ui.com/accessories/airgateway/

basically I need a wired connection for trialling vmware. The NIC chip on the motherboard is officially supported.

Thanks!

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/12.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-6F7ECBA6-A29A-40AE-B565-3D0F2E74FEA4.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the selected product will do what you want.

You would hook up the Ubiquiti device with an Ethernet cable to your router and set up wireless access at the router and with the Ubiquiti controller software. It does not hook up to your PC.

With respect to VMware, It works with a Wireless connection on your computer.

I have Ubiquiti (Access Point) here and VMware Workstation. All works fine with Wireless and there is no need to try to interconnect wired and wireless on your computer. These are separate and do not connect together.

You can trial VMware with a wireless connection on your computer.

If using a Server level VMware product, then use Ethernet for connectivity on the Server.  Wireless is not used / discouraged on Servers.

If necessary hook up the Server to a router and then possibly wireless from the router could be done (not certain about that).

Comment: I see your using workstation. I want to use the enterprise product.

Comment: It will still work with wireless unless using a Server with ESX in which case wireless does not apply (Servers do not use wireless)